# How to know if Array FileInfo[] contains a file

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, fileinfo

I have the following code, I receive an error at "if statement" saying that FileInfo does not contain a definition "Contains"

Which is the best solution for looking if a file is in a directory?

Thanks

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\";
DirectoryInfo folderRoot = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);
FileInfo[] fileList = folderRoot.GetFiles();

IEnumerable<FileInfo> result = from file in fileList where file.Name == "test.txt" select file;
if (fileList.Contains(result))
{
      //dosomething
}
```

Comment: You already moved the files into result, don't you just want to check the contents of result now?

Comment: you are queryng filelist for result, then how can fileList not contain result ?

Comment: Are you looking to see if *any* file is in a directory or if a *specific* file is in a directory?

Comment: @KDiTraglia yes, i want to check if the file "test.txt" is in the directory

Comment: @FelicePollano test.txt may not exist in the directory. At If statement i need to evaluate it.

Comment: @notfed if a specific file is in a directory, in this case "test.txt"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove `fileList.Contains(result)` and use:

```
if (result.Any())
{

}
```

`.Any()` is a LINQ keyword for determining whether result has any items in it or not. Kinda like doing a `.Count() > 0`, except [quicker](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2009/06/22/linq-any-vs-count/). With `.Any()`, as soon as an element is found the sequence is no longer enumerated, as the result is `True`.

In fact, you could remove the last five lines of your code from `from file in...` to the bottom, replacing it with:

```
if (fileList.Any(x => x.Name == "test.txt"))
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could check the count of result

```
 if (result.Count() > 0)
 {
    //dosomething
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, code below will give you a list of files (fullname as a string); the reason why return as a list is because your sub directories may have the same file name as 'test.txt'.

```
var list = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\temp\", "test.txt",
           SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

if you are very sure 'test.txt' file will only in one of the directory, you can use:

```
string fullname = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\temp\", "test.txt",
                  SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault();
if (fullname != null) { ..... }
```